# Using a linked list in python to simulate standing in line

Tags: python, linked-list

I have worked with linked lists and classes almost exclusively in c++, so I am having trouble getting this to work.  The first class is supposed to have the variables name and next, an init function, two getter functions, and two setter functions.  The second class(Line) is supposed to have an init function and an add function that adds items to the end of the linked list.  I can't seem to get my add function to work.  Any help is appreciated.

This is the code I have so far.

```
class PersonList():

    """
    The class to represent the node in a linked list of people.  It takes the variables:
    name, which represents the person's name, and next_person, which links the next
    person in the linked list.
    """
    def __init__(self, name = None, next_ = None):
        self.__name = name
        self.__next = next_

    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

    def getNext(self):
        return self.__next

    def setName(self, new_name):
        self.__name = new_name

    def setNext(self, new_person):
        self.__next = new_person

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.__name)

def printlist(node):
    next_node = node.getNext()
    while next_node != None:
        next_node = node.getNext()
        print (node)
        node = node.getNext()





class Line():

    """ The class that represents the line of people as the linked list.  Takes the variable
    head, that denotes the first person in the line
    """

    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = None


    def add(self, name):


        if self.head == None:
            self.head = PersonList(name)

        else:
```

Comment: What does *"can't seem to get [it] to work"* mean, exactly? You don't appear to have even finished implementing it...

Comment: Can you describe the behavior you see when you try and add a person? What happens vs what do you expect to happen?

Comment: in python, you probably dont need to implement this in the same way as in c. You could probably just get away with subclassing the `list` object in `Line()` so you inherit its `append()` and other list methods. Then just append and pop people on and off of it.

Comment: I spent about 3-4 hours trying different variations of the add function and testing them out in a main function.  All of my attempts have ended with one name that is not connected to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def add(self, name):
    if self.head == None:
        self.head = PersonList(name)
    else:
         tmp = self.head
         while tmp._next is not None: #while we are not at the end of the line
             tmp = tmp._next
         #end of line
         tmp._next = PersonList(name) #get in line at the end
```

is one option

Answer (score 1):

Or just keep track of the tail to avoid traversing the whole list each time you want to add something:

```
class Line():

""" The class that represents the line of people as the linked list.  Takes the variable
head, that denotes the first person in the line
"""

def __init__(self, head = None):
    self.head = None
    self.tail = None


def add(self, name):
    tmp = PersonList(name)
    if self.head == None:
        self.head = tmp
        self.tail = tmp
    else:
        self.tail.next = tmp
        self.tail = tmp
```

Comment: I suspect list traversal is part of the assignment +1 all the same since thats a much better solution